symbol of global map not "visible": how to share a global map from a shared library?
I have a library with several global maps:
in header (header0):
extern std::map<AVPixelFormat, std::string> AVPixelFormatMap;
extern std::map<AVMediaType, std::string> AVMediaTypeMap;
extern std::map<AVCodecID, std::string> AVCodecIDMap;

in cpp (cpp0):
std::map<AVPixelFormat, std::string> AVPixelFormatMap
{
    {AV_PIX_FMT_NONE, "AV_PIX_FMT_NONE: None"},

etc.
In another library, I include the header0 in the cpp file, and link to the file library0.lib, but the compiler complains with Error LNK2001:
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "class std::map<enum
> AVPixelFormat,class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct
> std::less<enum AVPixelFormat>,class std::allocator<struct
> std::pair<enum AVPixelFormat const ,class
> std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
> std::allocator<char> > > > > AVPixelFormatMap"
> (?AVPixelFormatMap@@3V?$map@W4AVPixelFormat@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@W4AVPixelFormat@@@3@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBW4AVPixelFormat@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@3@@std@@A)  library0    path/to\library0.obj    1

I tried extern __declspec(dllexport) std::map< the error remains.
I would like to use those maps in a shared library and not have to inline them in the other libraries using it.
What am I doing wrong ?

The variables must be exported by the dll and imported by the dll client.

I think it is better to expose the data via exported functions (not variables directly). Those functions can return a reference to the maps.

@3CxEZiVlQ Isn't what I did with the extern keyword in header ?

@Soleil no. That would be enough if you used it as a static library (it would have been used by the linker). But using a symbol from a DLL requires it to be properly exported. See more info here: Exporting from a DLL.

@wohlstad I edited the OP.
I tried `extern __declspec(dllexport) std::map<, the error remains.

@Soleil to be honest I never exported a variable from a DLL. Only functions (and classes). I also think it gives a cleaner interface, which is why I recommended it in a comment above. See the link above for info. Also see this post about exporting variables.

You also need a corresponing __declspec(dllimport) in the calling code. This is usually achieved by using a macro in the header file, that expands to __declspec(dllexport) when building the DLL and to __declspec(dllimport) otherwise.

@IgorTandetnik Indeed it worked.
